# Error starting spring boot "An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist"

Tags: maven, spring-boot

When i run the spring boot app, intellij returns me an error:

> An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.TypeContributorImpl.contribute(TypeContributorImpl.java:30)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributions.contributeJavaTypeDescriptor(Lorg/hibernate/type/descriptor/java/spi/JavaTypeDescriptor;)V
```

The method's class, org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributions, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/romul/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.6.Final/hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/boot/model/TypeContributions.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/romul/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.0.0.Alpha2/hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha2.jar!/org/hibernate/boot/model/TypeContributions.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/C:/Users/romul/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.6.Final/hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributions

This could be a conflict im my pom.xml?

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.produtos</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>api-rest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.26.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Alpha2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

How i can fix it?

Comment: Rebuild and return it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should not specify the version of Hibernate to use as the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency takes care of that.

If you run `mvn dependency:tree | grep hibernate`, you see that 2 versions of hibernate are included:

```
16:20 $ mvn dependency:tree | grep hibernate
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.6.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:jar:6.0.0.Alpha2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.4.8.Final:compile
```

It seems the group id changed from `org.hibernate` to `org.hibernate.orm`, that is why Maven does not notice it is the same library.

Also the `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency can be removed.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, i took the following steps.

1. I deleted the .m2 folder in  c:\users\ (Note its is hidden).
2. I was using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` so i removed the data-rest dependency completely
3. Close the project and open again (With internet connection), so the required dependency files will be downloaded again.

Comment: If you are using gradle wrapper you can delete `.gradle` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Delete your `.m2` folder in your user directory, e.g. `c:\users\<user-name>\.m2` and then run `maven install`. This will fix your classpath problem.

Answer (score 0):

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

I use the quick solution in my application for adding a new dependency then I rerun the java application then my error occur. After checking I found this dependency is the reason for the error. Just remove it and solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I Got the same problem,
I was building multi-module project in the parent pom file
was the dependency spring-boot-starter-parent and it is also exist in the children poms, so I delete the one in the parent and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

this is how IDEA helped me
file -> Invalidate caches﻿

after all dependencies are updated the error is cleared

Answer (score 0):

delete the repository under maven which cause the problem (eg. C:\Users\Administrator.m2\repository\xerces), then run it again.