# Error starting spring boot - "An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist"

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, gradle, version

I am trying to upgrade the Spring version for one of our projects.

The project structure is as listed below:

- `internalToolApp`
- `internalToolAppServiceTier`

The packages of the 2 sub-projects are listed below:

`build.gradle` of `internalToolApp`

```
buildscript {
   ext {
      springBootVersion = '2.6.9'
   }
   repositories {
      maven {
      url "https:..."
      credentials {
           username = "..."
           password = "..."
      }
      }
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.7.2'
      classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
   }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
if (project.hasProperty("projVersion")) {
    version =  project.projVersion
} else {
    version = "0.0-SNAPSHOT"
}

group = 'internalToolGroup'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    maven {
    url "https:..."
    credentials {
         username = "..."
         password = "..."
    }
    }
    maven {
    url "https:..."
    credentials {
         username = "..."
         password = "..."
    }
    }
    maven {
    url "https:..."
    credentials {
         username = "..."
         password = "..."
    }
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}


dependencies {
    compile project(':internalToolAppServiceTier')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.6.9')
    compile('com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot:2.1.0')
    compile 'com.visa.commons.security.protectconfig:protectconfig-core:2.7.0'
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:3.1.4')

    compile 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast-enterprise-all:4.2.1'
    compile("com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring:4.2.1")
    compile("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10")
    
    compile('org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.5.37')
    compile('org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.0.0')

    // Log4j 2
    compile ('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1')
    compile ('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1')
    compile ('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.17.1')
    
    compile ("commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6")
    compile('org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.2')
    compile('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2')
    
    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


bootJar {
    exclude ("application.properties")
    exclude ("database.properties")
    exclude ("filetransfer.properties")
    exclude ("mongo_local_application.properties")
}

task setupProject {
  doFirst {
    File dir = new File("$buildDir/../../../coreconfig_commons")
    if(!dir.exists()) {
        def grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.clone(dir: "$buildDir/../../../anotherInternalTool", uri: "https://.....git")
    }
  }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

`build.gradle` of `internalToolAppServiceTier`

```
buildscript {
   ext {
      springBootVersion = '2.6.9'
   }
   repositories {
      maven {
      url "https:..."
      credentials {
           username = "..."
           password = "..."
      }
      }
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.7.2'
      classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
   }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
if (project.hasProperty("projVersion")) {
    version =  project.projVersion
} else {
    version = "0.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
group = 'internalToolGroup'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    maven {
    url "https:..."
    credentials {
         username = "..."
         password = "..."
    }
    }
    maven {
    url "https:..."
    credentials {
         username = "..."
         password = "..."
    }
    }
}
configurations.all {
    if (!project.hasProperty("local")) {
        resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
}

dependencies {
    
    if (project.hasProperty("local")) {
        compile project(':CommonServiceTier')
        compile project(':CommonUtility')
        compile project(':CommonDBTier')
    } else {
        compile(group: 'internalToolGroup', name: 'CommonServiceTier', version: version){ changing = true }
        compile(group: 'internalToolGroup', name: 'CommonUtility', version: version){ changing = true }
        compile(group: 'internalToolGroup', name: 'CommonDBTier', version: version){ changing = true }
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.6.9')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-tx:5.0.12.RELEASE')

    compile('com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot:2.1.0')
    compile 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast-enterprise-all:4.2.1'
    compile("com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring:4.2.1")
    compile("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10") 
    
    compile("org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.9.1") 
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:3.2.0')
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.4'
    compile('org.mybatis:mybatis:3.5.0')
    compile('org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:2.0.0')
    compile 'org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7'
    compile 'org.apache.velocity.tools:velocity-tools-generic:3.0'
    compile('org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.2')
    compile('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2')
    
    compile('com.ibm.db2:db2jcc_license_cisuz:1.0')
        compile('com.ibm.db2:db2java:1.0')
        compile('com.ibm.db2:jcc:11.5.0.0')

    // Log4j 2
    compile ('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1')
    compile ('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1')
    compile ('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.17.1')

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this project `internalToolApp`, i get some output, showing that the application is able to run, but after some time, the application fails & i get below error in the console:

```
[2023-01-26 16:59:55,238] [CompanyInternalTool] -- [...]- [main] WARN  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext [] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder.uuidRepresentation(Lorg/bson/UuidRepresentation;)Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientSettings$Builder;
Jan 26, 2023 4:59:55 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_1 [dev] [4.2.1] HazelcastClient 4.2.1 (20210630 - 6145014, 06a4018) is SHUTTING_DOWN
Jan 26, 2023 4:59:55 PM com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_1 [dev] [4.2.1] Removed connection to endpoint: [10.93.88.241]:5701:2c82e08d-47f2-44ef-a24e-d539a81aac35, connection: ClientConnection{alive=false, connectionId=1, channel=NioChannel{/127.0.0.1:55728->localhost/127.0.0.1:5701}, remoteAddress=[10.93.88.241]:5701, lastReadTime=2023-01-26 16:59:54.312, lastWriteTime=2023-01-26 16:59:54.283, closedTime=2023-01-26 16:59:55.241, connected server version=4.2.1}
Jan 26, 2023 4:59:55 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_1 [dev] [4.2.1] HazelcastClient 4.2.1 (20210630 - 6145014, 06a4018) is CLIENT_DISCONNECTED
Jan 26, 2023 4:59:55 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_1 [dev] [4.2.1] HazelcastClient 4.2.1 (20210630 - 6145014, 06a4018) is SHUTDOWN
Jan 26, 2023 4:59:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoPropertiesClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer.applyUuidRepresentation(MongoPropertiesClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer.java:67)

The following method did not exist:

    com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder.uuidRepresentation(Lorg/bson/UuidRepresentation;)Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientSettings$Builder;

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoPropertiesClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/hyusuf/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.6.9/143e3b88bbf01a87d4877196c715e3b154d5e00c/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.9.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoPropertiesClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/hyusuf/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.6.11/40e0e3011e8549b4591a0a3f26d21ba5978b6ed1/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.11.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoPropertiesClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer.class

The calling method's class was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/hyusuf/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.6.9/143e3b88bbf01a87d4877196c715e3b154d5e00c/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.9.jar

The called method's class, com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/hyusuf/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.9.1/d313237180bf9f2f82e12f503d9617e6b070f792/mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar!/com/mongodb/MongoClientSettings$Builder.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/hyusuf/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.2.3/ac8159055a465139c643355aa3af7f4c050bceb2/mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/com/mongodb/MongoClientSettings$Builder.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.Builder: file:/C:/Users/hyusuf/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.9.1/d313237180bf9f2f82e12f503d9617e6b070f792/mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoPropertiesClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer and com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder
```

I found a similar StackOverflow post [here]([Error starting spring boot "An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58671257/15781733)) that seems to indicate there is a duplicate package, I'm not quite sure how to detect that as I'm new to this.

Would anyone be able to provide a solution or guidance on what I should do?

---

Following @Pritam Sadhukhan's suggestion, i get the same error, althought slightly different, it mentions different versions of the same package causing issues

```
[2023-01-30 11:39:20,876] [CompanyInternalTool] -- [...]- [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication [] - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration$JdbcTransactionManagerConfiguration': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration$JdbcTransactionManagerConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1302) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:745) [spring-boot-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:420) [spring-boot-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1317) [spring-boot-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
    at com.visa.coreconfig.pedit.CoreConfigPeditApp.main(CoreConfigPeditApp.java:154) [main/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration$JdbcTransactionManagerConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/support/JdbcTransactionManager
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: You are using incompatible combinations, the error tells you exactly which (2 versions of spring-boot-autoconfigure, probably pulled in by spring-cloud. You are also using a wrong version of `spring-tx`. So it looks like you are having a bit of a mess with your dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum hi, thanks for your prompt response! which version of `spring-tx` should i be using?

Comment: You should remove the version, or even better remove the monog stuff as well and use `spring-boot-starter-data-mongo` instead to pull in all you need. Remove the `version` from the `spring-boot-starter` dependencies as those are managed by the Spring Boot plugin. Replace jackson with `spring-boot-starter-json` to get all needed dependencies.

Comment: hi @M.Deinum, if i understood you correctly, replace 
`compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.4' compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.4' compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.4'`
with 
`compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-boot-starter-json'`,

remove `compile("org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.9.1")` completely 

and replace `compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.6.9')` with `compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')`?

Comment: would you be able to post an answer? apologies as i'm very new to this, i'm having a bit of difficulty following along with what the `build.gradle` should look like?

Comment: hi @M.Deinum, i've posted an answer to show what i understood, help me point out if it's correct or any changes i need to make

Comment: Plesae don't use an answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Deinum,

Is this what the `build.gradle` should look like?

1. `jackson`

Replace

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.4'
}
```

with

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-boot-starter-json')
}
```

2. `mongo`

Remove

```
compile("org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.9.1") 
compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:3.2.0')
```

with

```
compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:3.2.0')
```

3. `spring-boot-starter-web`

Replace

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.6.9')
```

with

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
```

Is this all? or did i miss something

Comment: and no the mongo stuff isn't correct I stat ed replace it with `spring-boot-starter-data-mongo`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change the `build.gradle` of `internalToolAppServiceTier` and replace the following respectively?

```
compile('org.springframework:spring-tx:5.3.21')
```

Replace

```
compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:3.2.0')
```

to

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.7.2'
```

Comment: do i retain `compile("org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.9.1") `? Or does `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.7.2` take care of that?

Comment: Please retain the driver.

Comment: hi @Pritam, i followed your suggestion but i am getting the same error, i've updated the last part of my question with the output following your suggestion

Comment: Please try with removing `compile("org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.9.1") `. Seems like same dependency is injected from two sources with different versions.

Comment: hi Pritam, i encountered an error this time, although the error message is different, something about a spring package missing, i've updated my question with the console output when removing `mongo-java-driver`. What should i write in `build.gradle` to retrieve this missing spring package?

Comment: hi Pritam, it seems that the package `"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration"` can't be found. I'm using Eclipse, from the Referenced Libraries, it seems that `spring-boot-2.7.2.jar` is being used. Looking at the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.2/api/index.html, i can see that my spring-boot-2.7.2.jar is missing some libraries that the docs listed, any idea why?

Comment: Can you please update the `build.gradle` files? Also my mistake on the version for `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.7.2` which should be `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.6.9` as you are using `2.6.9` as spring boot version.

Comment: Please try with `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.6.9'` or `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.6.9'` for the missing class you mentioned in error logs.

Comment: hi Pritam, it worked, thank you so much! going forward, how did you know to use the `'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.6.9'`? because before your answer, i did `'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.6.9'` which targeted the missing package but it still didn't work

Comment: Hi @waffledood, I just saw the error messages and identified there are multiple versions of same jar which gives the meaning.